# How do you convert option to None?

Tags: scala, monads, option-type

Consider [example](http://scastie.org/13475)

```
object Main extends App {
  case class ref(val target: Object)
  val map: Map[Int, ref] = Map(1 -> ref(null), 2 -> ref("2")) 
                                            //> map  : Map[Int,o.ref] = Map(1 -> ref(null), 2 -> ref(2))

  def request(id: Int, default: Object) = {
    println(map.get(id) map (_.target) match {
      case Some(result) => result
      case None => default
    })
  }                                         //> request: (id: Int, default: Object)Unit
  request(0, "fixed 0")                     //> fixed 0
  request(1, "fixed 1")                     //> null
  request(2, "fixed 2")                     //> 2
}
```

As you see, option1 results in null. I want such targets to handle likewise there is no match in the db. How do I convert `Some(null)` to `None`?

Comment: Generally I would look at where the 'target' values are coming from, and wrap them in `Option` as close to that point as possible. Then, 'null' values would already be `None`, while non-null values would be `Some(target)`. Call, for example,  `.map(ref)` on this to get `None`/`Some(ref)`, call `.foreach` on that to put the entry in the map (so it goes in only if it is not `None`), etc.

Comment: Targets are coming from weak references. I do not want to spend a lot of memory storing everything in the Option wrappers. The idea to convert it on the fly, however, makes some sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
map (_.target) filter (_ != null)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want to convert a value that may be `null` into an `Option`, just build it like so:

```
Option(ref)
```

In your case, since you want an inner field to become an `Option`, you can just `flatMap`:

```
map.get(id).flatMap(ref => Option(ref.target))
```

---

I would rewrite your `request` method so:

```
def request(id: Int, default: Object) =
  println(map.get(id).flatMap(ref => Option(ref.target)).getOrElse(default))
```

`Option`'s apply method does exactly what you want, if you pass it a `null`, it will return a `None`, that's how the `flatMap` bit works.

Comment: Mapping all map values seems overkill. `map.get(id).filter(_.target != null).getOrElse(default)` [is just fine](http://scastie.org/13478).

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov I updated my answer to accomodate your suggestion. The exact expression you wrote would return `ref`, not target, you need to `map` it before the `getOrElse` part.

Comment: `mapValues` doesn't actually map but creates a view that will apply the mapping function on demand. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.MapLike@mapValues[C]%28%28B%29%E2%87%92C%29:Map[A,C]

Comment: Yes, you are all right. I have selected Lee's answer coz it addresses the real question, how to convert Some(null) => None in most concise form. But your remarks are appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Up do date, my best match was to use flatMap

```
map (_.target) flatMap { case null => None ; case a => Some(a) }
```

Comment: This is equivalent to: map(_.target).flatMap(item=>Option(item))

Answer (score 0):

Calling `map.get(1)` will return `Some(ref(null))`. Doing `Some(ref(null)) map (_.target)` results in `Some(null)`. That is why you get null. You could do this instead:

```
def request(id: Int, default: Object) = {
    println(map.get(id).flatMap(r => Option(r.target)).getOrElse(default))
}
```

Now `request(1, "fixed 1")` will print `fixed 1`.

Also, your final `match` expression can be shortened to `getOrElse(default)`.